# Лабораторная, нарушение прав доступа при записи

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017

при вводе переменных отладчик ругается на: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x5C25D4EC (ucrtbased.dll) в lab2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00740000. Дальше первой строки уйти не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

/*******************************************************/
/*           Лабораторная  работа №2                   */
/*          Типы данных и ввод-вывод                   */
/*        Пример выполнения. Вариант №12.              */
/*******************************************************/

using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

//Определение переменных
char tr[5], ts[5], a[5], route3;
float dist1, dist2, dist3;
int route1, route2, time1, time2, time3;

//Ввод данных
printf("Введите первый вид транспорта, маршрут, протяженность, время в дороге: ");
scanf_s("%s %d %f %d", tr, &route1, &dist1, &time1);
printf("Введите второй вид транспорта, маршрут, протяженность, время в дороге: ");
scanf_s("%s %d %f %d", ts, &route2, &dist2, &time2);
printf("Введите третий вид транспорта, маршрут, протяженность, время в дороге: ");
scanf_s("%s %с %f %d", a, &route3, &dist3, &time3);

//Вывод данных
printf("%5s %d %2.2f\n", tr, route1, dist1, time1);
printf("%5s %d %2.2f\n", ts, route2, dist2, time2);
printf("%5s %c %2.2f\n", a, route3, dist3, time3);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для чего вы подключаете все из std?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в стандартной библиотеке C++ нет функции scanf_s (например). Судя по всему, это написано там просто так :)

Comment: Просто так, пусть компилятор  побольше поработает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас включены предупреждения? тогда при компиляции VC++ вы должны были видеть предупреждения типа

> rrr.cpp(23): warning C4477: "scanf_s": в строке форматирования "%s" требуется аргумент типа "unsigned int", но вариативный аргумент "2" имеет тип "int *"

```
//Ввод данных
printf("Введите первый вид транспорта, маршрут, протяженность, время в дороге: ");
scanf_s("%s %d %f %d", tr, 4, &route1, &dist1, &time1);
printf("Введите второй вид транспорта, маршрут, протяженность, время в дороге: ");
scanf_s("%s %d %f %d", ts, 4, &route2, &dist2, &time2);
printf("Введите третий вид транспорта, маршрут, протяженность, время в дороге: ");
scanf_s("%s %c %f %d", a, 4, &route3, 1, &dist3, &time3);

//Вывод данных
printf("%5s %d %2.2f\n", tr, route1, dist1);
printf("%5s %d %2.2f\n", ts, route2, dist2);
printf("%5s %c %2.2f\n", a, route3, dist3);
```

Непонятно, почему у вас вдруг в третьем вводе маршрут стал `char`'ом, но хозяин - барин...

Убрал также ненужные переменные `time` при выводе (о них тоже предупреждал компилятор).